# Consulta MySql no trae datos

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto con dos tablas, cursos y alumnos , quiero traer el numero de alumnos inscritos por curso en una nueva columna de la consulta y cuando no tenga alumnos inscritos el curso me muestre 0, pero cuando hago la consulta los cursos que no tienen alumnos se llena con el total de alumnos

[image: my]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
introducir el código aquí

SELECT c.nombre,ifnull(COUNT(a.documento),0)AS conteo 
FROM cursos c,alumnos a 
WHERE a.cursos_id_curso=c.id_curso or c.id_curso NOT IN (
  SELECT DISTINCT a.cursos_id_curso ifnull 
  FROM alumnos a 
)
GROUP BY c.nombre;
```

Comment: Creo que te lías demasiado en tu consulta. Recomiendo que uses `JOIN`, pues permite más claridad en las consultas. Esto debería funcionar:  `SELECT c.nombre, COUNT(*) AS conteo FROM cursos c INNER JOIN alumnos a ON c.id_curso = a.cursos_id_curso GROUP BY c.id_curso`

Comment: gracias pero ya lo había probado asi y la consulta solo me trae los cursos con alumnos inscritos pues en mi tabla alumno no tiene registrados los id_curso que tienen cero en el count

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba usando un subquery para que se vuelva mas sencillo

```
SELECT 
  c.nombre, 
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM alumnos a WHERE a.cursos_id_curso = c.id_curso) conteo
FROM cursos c
```

Comment: gracias bro, quedo a la perfección

Answer (score -1):

creo que podes simplificarlo así:

```
select c.nombre, count(*) as conteo
from cursos c 
    left join alumnos a on c. id_curso=a.cursos_id_curso group by c.nombre
```

Usando left join te aparecen los cursos aunque no tuviesen inscritos.

Comment: De esta forma no me trae todos los cursos pues en mi tabla alumno esos id_curso que están con cero estudiantes no son referencia para la tabla cursos pues no existen aun, igualmente mil gracias por tu explicación asi voy entendiendo mas como funcionan los join